# Setting the visibility for a ThumbnailToolBarButton

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, thumbnail-toolbar

I've got a few `ThumbnailToolBarButtons` on my window thumbnail.  One is a play/pause button.  I've actually got two buttons for this ... one for play and one for pause.  When I click the button it will hide one and show the other using the `ThumbnailToolBarButton`'s Visible property.  However, while the window thumbnail is up if I click the play/pause button the `ThumbnailToolBarButtons` all get really wide and suddenly I only see two buttons.  If I let the window thumbnail disappear and roll over it again all my buttons are back and the correct widths.  What is going on here?  Thanks.

**Update:** Ok.  Here is some code as an example.

```
private ThumbnailToolBarButton buttonPrevious;
private ThumbnailToolBarButton buttonNext;
private ThumbnailToolBarButton buttonPlay;
private ThumbnailToolBarButton buttonPause;
private Boolean bPlaying = false;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonPrevious = new ThumbnailToolBarButton(Properties.Resources.previous, "Previous");
    buttonPrevious.Click += new EventHandler<ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs>(buttonPrevious_Click);
    buttonPrevious.Visible = true;

    buttonNext = new ThumbnailToolBarButton(Properties.Resources.next, "Next");
    buttonNext.Click += new EventHandler<ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs>(buttonNext_Click);
    buttonNext.Visible = true;

    buttonPlay = new ThumbnailToolBarButton(Properties.Resources.play, "Pause/Pause");
    buttonPlay.Click += new EventHandler<ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs>(buttonPlay_Click);
    buttonPlay.Visible = true;

    buttonPause = new ThumbnailToolBarButton(Properties.Resources.pause, "Play");
    buttonPause.Click += new EventHandler<ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs>(buttonPlay_Click);
    buttonPause.Visible = false;

    TaskbarManager.Instance.ThumbnailToolBars.AddButtons(this.Handle, buttonPrevious, buttonPlay, buttonPause, buttonNext);
}

private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, ThumbnailButtonClickedEventArgs e)
{
    bPlaying = !bPlaying;

    buttonPlay.Visible = bPlaying ? false : true;
    buttonPause.Visible = bPlaying ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe instead of showing one and hiding the other I should just be swapping out the image, but alas I've scoured the web and cannot find out how to do it.

Comment: can you edit your question with some code showing us how you are using the ThumbnailToolBarButtons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uniting the play/pause buttons into one button, and in the click event handler write:

```
if ( buttonPlayPause.Icon == Properties.Resources.play )
    buttonPlayPause.Icon = Properties.Resources.pause;
else
    buttonPlayPause.Icon = Properties.Resources.play;
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried.  It doesn't actually change the icon ... you would think it would, but nope.

Comment: Since, I'm gonna lose the reputation points anyway, and you are the only one to answer and the bounty ends in a few minutes you can have the bounty.  Might as well give it to someone.

Comment: Wha!? Ok, now it works. Color me confused. Oh, well.  Bounty earned then. Thanks.